# Сумма двух чисел на CUDA выдает всегда ноль

Tags: cuda

Сразу к делу: есть программный код на CUDA, который должен посчитать сумму двух чисел. Насколько известно (сверялся с несколькими источниками) код верный, но результат всегда 0. Помогите, пожалуйста, установить причину данной проблемы.
ОС: Windows 10
IDE: Visual Studio Community 2019
NVIDIA CUDA: 11.4
Видеокарта на ноуте: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
Если нужны еще данные какие-нибудь, могу все написать

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void add( int *a, int *b, int *c )
{
    *c = *a + *b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int host_a, host_b, host_c; // CPU
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c; // GPU

    int size = sizeof(int);
    
    // выделем память на устройстве (device)
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, size );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, size );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, size );

    // входные значений
    host_a = 2;
    host_b = 7;

    // копируем входные значения на устройства
    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, &host_a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_b, &host_b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    // запускаем add() на ядре GPU
    add<<< 1,1 >>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c );

    // копируем результат обратно на хост
    cudaMemcpy( &host_c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    // очистка
    cudaFree( dev_a );
    cudaFree( dev_b );
    cudaFree( dev_c );
   
    printf( "%d\n", host_c );
    return 0;
}
```

P.s.: переход на Linux и нормальная работа там - не актуально для меня на данный момент
Дополнительно: отложил ноут в сторону, установил CUDA Toolkit 11.4 на домашний компьютер, запустил эту же программу -> все заработало, сумма считается. Вопрос остается актуальным: почему на ноуте не поднимается?

Comment: Нет ни одной проверки успешности проводимых операций. Кроме того, работая на ноуте, следует озадачиваться принудительной активацией дискретного адаптера.

Comment: 1) Я с кудой начал только знакомиться, эта задача в источнике была как "hello world", поэтому проверок нет. У источника программа запускалась нормально  
2) принудительная активация дискретного адаптера? можно поподробнее что требуется для этого?

Comment: 1) Проверки обязательны, даже несмотря на то, что может работать и без них. 2) без понятия

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблему на ноутбуке решил: у меня на ноуте Compute capability (version) 5.0.
[image: информация о ведюхе через cuda]
Проект по дефолту в Visual Studio создается под 5.2, а в списке видюх для 5.2 моей NVIDIA GeForce 940MX нету.
[image: скрин с википедии]
Само решение: я вручную поменял все значения (для дебага и релиза) 52 на 50, собрал проект и все полетело без проблем
[image: свойства проекта]